# Determinant of $\vert A' C A\vert$

Tags: matrices, statistics, determinant

Let $X$ be an $n\times p$ real matrix with column rank $k$, where $0<k<p<n$, and let $A$ be a semi-orthogonal matrix (the columns are orthonormal) such that $A'X=0$, i.e. the column space of $A$ is the orthogonal complement to the column space of $X$. Let $C$ be an arbitrary positive definite $n\times n$ matrix.

**Question:**
*Can the determinant $\vert A'CA \vert $ be expressed as a function of $X$ and $C$?*

When $p=k$ so that $X$ is full column rank, the answer is *yes* and one can write $\vert A'CA\vert = \vert A'A\vert\vert C\vert\vert X'C^{-1}X\vert/\vert X'X\vert$. This is equation (9) in [LaMotte](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00362-006-0335-6). I have thought about relating the non-zero singular values of $X$ and $C$ to those of $A'CA$ but haven't succeeded.

This question is related to a question of more statistical nature posted on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203216/restricted-maximum-likelihood-with-less-than-full-column-rank-of-x) in the sense than an answer to the present question may be a help on the way to finding an answer to the statistical question.